# Random authentication failures on a load balanced WP setup

Tags: wp-admin, authentication

**1 Wordpress instance**

I have a wordpress setup on one EC2 with a MySQL DB on another server. This setup works fine for both the blog access and `wp-admin`.

**2 Wordpress instances**

I repeat a similar setup but this time with WP setup across 2 EC2s with a MySQL DB on another server. The blog works fine and I can see the traffic balanced between bother application servers. However, when I try to authenticate to `wp-admin`, it successfully authenticates randomly. In case it fails, it redirects to the login form without any errors.

When it does successfully authenticates into the admin and I refresh the page a random number of times, it will redirect me back to the admin login form with no errors.

What is happening in the above scenario? After authentication succeed, where does WP store the token? In memory or database(if so which table)?

Comment: you will probably have to explain better how the load balancer is configured, especially if it ties sessions to specific server

Comment: ... and which kind of caching you use

Comment: I am not using any caching. The session is not tied to specific server. This might be the cause of the issue. How is that session stored in WP? Does it store in memory or database?

Comment: if you do not use any caching, than there should not be any problem. The fact that there is means that either you have caching going wrong at some level or some kind of code that does something which is local to the server and therefor the other server fails to be updated. the other option is misconfiguration of the LB. I would try binding each session to a specific server, something that the LB should be able to be configured to do.